# PHP + Sabre Web services

Tags: sabre

I am trying to using sabre web service in one of my php application.

But I am confuse how to implement it.

I done lots of R & D on google but still not get result.

Has anyone solution ? please guide.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Array
(
    [error] => invalid_client
    [error_description] => Credentials are missing or the syntax is not correct
)  i got this error any one can help me to solve out this

Answer (score 1):

You should look into PHPs Soap Client APIs:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Answer (score 1):

To use sabre php, you will need to create a session with the username and logins. In the session there will be a token which you include in your soap request.

You could either use SOAPUI or just post to the endpoint with a xml.

To get fares back, it is best to use BargainFinderMax.

Answer (score -3):

Why have to be with PHP?

Sabre SOAP model is easy to consume using .NET, just point to the Service WSDL, instanciate the service, create the request object, pass it to the service then get the response and mapp to a custom object.